# Cannot connect to port on vps

Tags: php, sockets, port, vps

My PHP script opens port using socket like:

```
$socket = stream_socket_server('tcp://127.0.0.1:' . $this->port, $errno, $errstr);
```

For example say port is 58889.

I cannot connect to port from telnet (Connection refused).

Here is what 'netstat -plunt' command shows:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58889         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13849/php       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58890         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13841/php       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58891         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13857/php       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

There is no special firewall rules on hosting provider. How to fix it?

Comment: You are only listening on the `localhost` ip address? Should you be listening on the `external` ip address (0.0.0.0 means all addesses on the machine) as well? Unless you just want to connect from the same machine?

Comment: Thank you )) You are absolutely right!

Comment: @RyanVincent format it into an answer so Eugene can accept it...

Comment: @RyanVincent first point is true for Eugene 'cause he is new to SE. but really, this is how the site works... and how google index it. and how questions are filtered. + i gave you some rating feedback on the answer, so it worth it ;)

Comment: @TomerW, thanks  for the upvote. It is appreciated - I like being here on 'SO' , is fun :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the TCP server is only listening for connections on the `localhost` IP address.

This will only allow connections from the 'local' machine.

To specify to listen for connections on all the IP addresses on the machine, which will allow connections from external machines, then use an IP Address of '0.0.0.0' (IPv4):

```
stream_socket_server('tcp://0.0.0.0:' . $this->port, $errno, $errstr);
```